# Spl token not getting minted using spl js library

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library

Here's my code i'm trying to mint spl token using spl js library:

```
(async () => {
  const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

  let secretKey = Uint8Array.from([
    186, 104, 237, 47, 123, 227, 2, 226, 150, 7, 169, 40, 252, 67, 161, 86, 198,....
    183, 130, 31, 174, 135, 153, 46, 227, 154, 125, 20, 79, 209,
  ]);

  const myKeypair = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);

  console.log(myKeypair.publicKey);
  
  mint = await splToken.createMint(
    connection,
    myKeypair,
    myKeypair.publicKey,
    null,
    9,
    splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  console.log("mint:"+mint);
})();
```

This is the error im getting:

solana/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1791
const key = signer.publicKey.toString();
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
at Transaction.sign solana/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:1791:36)
at Connection.sendTransaction solana/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:9676:21)

Comment: does that `Uin8Array.from` has `,,,,` or it happened by mistake when you paste the code?

Comment: @Yilmaz I imagine he'd redacting part of his secret key to avoid getting robbed.

Comment: @SM It's better to just omit the entire secret key. We'll understand why you're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

those are the parameters for `createMint()`

```
@param connection — Connection to use

@param payer — Payer of the transaction and initialization fees

@param mintAuthority — Account or multisig that will control minting

@param freezeAuthority — Optional account or multisig that can freeze token accounts

@param decimals — Location of the decimal place

@param keypair — Optional keypair, defaulting to a new random one
```

Last one type is `Keypair`. but you are passing `splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID` which is `PublicKey`. you need to create another keypair for the last arg